# Xpath Expression to retrieve the subsequent nodes of a parent node which is not related by a common attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

The input xml

```
    <bill>
    <bill_detail>
    <detail type="T1" heading="PS"> 
      <section type="T1" heading="P1" sub_heading="A"> 
        <data_line type="T1"> 
          <text1>Employees</text1>  
          <text2>1</text2>  
          <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <total_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Total</text1>  
      <text3>1</text3>  
      <text4>2</text4>  
      <text5>3</text5> 
    </total_line> 
  </section>  
  <section type="T1" sub_heading="B"> 
    <data_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Single</text1>  
      <text2>1</text2>  
      <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <data_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Family</text1>  
      <text2>1</text2>  
      <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <total_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Total</text1>  
      <text3>1</text3>  
      <text4>2</text4>  
      <text5>3</text5> 
    </total_line> 
  </section>  
  <section type="T1" sub_heading="C"> 
    <data_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Employees</text1>  
      <text2>1</text2>  
      <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <total_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Total</text1>  
      <text3>1</text3>  
      <text4>2</text4>  
      <text5>3</text5> 
    </total_line> 
  </section>
  <section type="T1" heading="P2" sub_heading="A"> 
    <data_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Employees</text1>  
      <text2>1</text2>  
      <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <total_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Total</text1>  
      <text3>1</text3>  
      <text4>2</text4>  
      <text5>3</text5> 
    </total_line> 
  </section>  
  <section type="T1" sub_heading="B"> 
    <data_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Single</text1>  
      <text2>1</text2>  
      <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <data_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Family</text1>  
      <text2>1</text2>  
      <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <total_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Total</text1>  
      <text3>1</text3>  
      <text4>2</text4>  
      <text5>3</text5> 
    </total_line> 
  </section>  
  <section type="T1" sub_heading="C"> 
    <data_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Employees</text1>  
      <text2>1</text2>  
      <text3>2</text3>  
      <text4>3</text4>  
      <text5>4</text5> 
    </data_line>  
    <total_line type="T1"> 
      <text1>Total</text1>  
      <text3>1</text3>  
      <text4>2</text4>  
      <text5>3</text5> 
    </total_line> 
  </section>  
</detail>
</bill_detail>
</bill>
```

The output i am looking for is

1. For the section which has sub_heading="A" and heading="P1" find the
   2 sections below it with sub_heading="B" and sub_heading="C"
2. The xpath expression should still hold good if i change the heading  to P2. It should be able to give the sections below the node which has the heading which is given as input.

What i have tried so far -

```
//section[contains(@sub_heading, 'A') and @heading = 'P1']//following-sibling::section[@sub_heading = 'C' or @sub_heading = 'B']
```

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/6b6b92a5d3fc3a8f8b74346da8d2a208

Comment: I guess your problem is that there are multiple following siblings matching your criteria. You'll have to define the selection better. What differentiates the first B/C sub-heading sections from the latter two?

Comment: @Phil As part of the above xpath expression i am getting 4 section nodes , the latter 2 which is under the section node having heading as P2. I am looking for the first 2 section nodes under the heading P1 which has sub_heading as B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tack this on the end of your expression

```
[position() <= 2]
```

<kbd>[xPath tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0f930869b4c8dbe64be00af0b647fc32)</kbd>

---

Take heed that if the first two following siblings are both "B" or "C", you will only get those and not one "B" and one "C". You might not run into this with your data but if it's a possibility, you'll need to construct a more complex expression.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Apart from position() <= 2 is there any other way this can be done dynamically ?

Comment: @jithz not with the criteria you've provided. You'll need something else to look for besides *"the first two..."*